# Performing double induction in Welder

Tags: leon

I'm trying to proof a property by double induction using Welder. The definitions are taken from [here](http://www.russinoff.com/papers/shnf.pdf). A related question that gives more details of the theory can be found [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/75608/complex-property-of-sparse-horner-polynomials-by-induction). Anyways I just need some portion to show my problem:

Basically, I'm working with expressions that take the form of an integer, `POP(i,p)` and `POW(i,p,q)`. There is a property of normality on them call it n. I want to proof that if `n(x) && n(y)` then `n(x+y)`.

Let's look at the specific case `x = POP(i,p)`, `y = POP(j,q)` then `x+y` is defined as follows:

```
if i = j then pop(i,p+q)
if i > j then pop(j,POP(i-j,p)+q)
if i < j then pop(i,POP(j-i,q)+p)
```

where `pop` is a function that mimics `POP` constructs with some slight differences.

I perform the proof by double induction in Welder as follows:

```
def property(x: Expr) = {
  forall("y" :: shf){ case (y) => 
    (n(x) && n(y)) ==> n(x+y)
  } 
}
structuralInduction(property _, "x" :: shf) { case (ihs1, goal1) =>
  val xi = ihs1.expression
  xi match{
  ...
```

The relevant case I want to focus is the following:

```
case C(`POP_ID`,i,pshf) =>
  def popproperty(y: Expr) = { 
    n(y) ==> n(xi+y) 
  }
  structuralInduction(popproperty _, "y" :: shf) { case (ihs2, goal2) =>
   val yi = ihs2.expression
   implI(n(yi)){ axioms2 =>
    yi match{
     case C(`constshfID`, fc) => andI(ihs1.hypothesis(pshf),axioms1)
     case C(`POP_ID`,j,qshf) => 
      andI(
       implE(forallE(normpop1Lemma)(i,normadd(pshf,qshf)))( g => 
        andI(implE(forallE(ihs1.hypothesis(pshf))(qshf))( g => 
         andI(axioms1,axioms2)), axioms1, axioms2)),
       implI(i > j){ gt => 
        implE(forallE(normpop1Lemma)(i,normadd(POP(i-j,pshf),qshf)))( g => 
         andI(implE(ihs2.hypothesis(qshf))(g => axioms2),axioms1,axioms2,gt))                            
       },
       implI(i < j){ lt => 
        implE(forallE(normpop1Lemma)(i,normadd(POP(j-i,pshf),qshf)))( g => 
         andI(implE(ihs2.hypothesis(qshf))(g => axioms2),axioms1,axioms2,lt))
                            
    }
   )
```

Here `normpop1Lemma` states that for having `n(pop(i,p))` you need `i` to be natural and `p` normal. However, I find that the second case is not proved. In fact I would need to generalize the second property to

```
def popproperty(y: Expr) = { 
  forall("x" :: shf){
   n(y) ==> n(x+y) 
  }
}
```

but then am I not breaking induction? Can I actually solve the cases `i > j` and `i < j` by doing so? (more to come while I experiment)

**Edit**

Currently, I can induct first on y and then on x and for the POP-POP case I can show the cases where `i = j` and `i > j` but the `i < j` is not. I thought it could work by using that `POP(j-i,q) + p = p + POP(j-i,q)` but it doesn't.

Instead, now I'm  trying to proof two different properties assuming in each that the one of the cases cannot hold (either the `i < j` or the `i > j`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, I would expect your proof to look something more like this:

```
structuralInduction((x: Expr) =>
  forall("y" :: shf)(y => (n(x) && n(y)) ==> n(x+y)), "x" :: shf
) { case (ihs1, g1) =>
  structuralInduction((y: Expr) =>
    (n(ihs1.expression) && n(y)) ==> n(ihs1.expression+y), "y" :: shf
  ) { case (ihs2, g2) =>
    implI(n(ihs1.expression) && n(ihs2.expression)) { normalXY =>
      (ihs1.expression, ihs2.expression) match {
        case (C(`POP_ID`,i,pshf), C(`POP_ID`,j,qshf)) => andI(
           ... // case (i == j)
           ... // case (i > j)
           implI(i < j) { iLtJ =>
             andI(
               ... // stuff using normprop1Lemma
               implE(forallE(ihs1.hypothesis(pshf))(normadd(POP(j-i,qshf)) {
                 g => // the reason why n(normadd(POP(j-i,qshf)) and n(pshf)
               },
               ... // invoke some lemma showing x+y == y+x
             )
           }
        )
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here we use the induction hypothesis from the outer induction since we're performing induction on `p \in x`. I assume `normprop1Lemma` is telling you that `normadd(POP(j-i,qshf))` is in normal form. You will probably need some lemma stating that `p \in x` is in normal form if `x` is in normal form.

Hope this helps!